# My converter does not activate/work

Tags: jsp, jsf, converters

I need a converter for `<h:selectOneMenu>`. I created it, but my object still displays like `com.ddd.bo.Firm@9f36e691`.

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{configBean.user.firm}" convert="firmConverter" required="true" label="#{bundle.config_form_add_firm}" > 
    <f:selectItems value="#{configBean.firmsLazyList}" />                  
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

In `faces-config-general.xml`, I have placed:

```
<converter>
    <converter-for-class>com.ddd.bo.Firm</converter-for-class>
    <converter-class>com.ddd.bo.converter.FirmConverter</converter-class>
</converter>
```

and in `FirmConverter.java`:

```
@FacesConverter(forClass=Firm.class)
public class FirmConverter implements Converter {

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String newValue) throws ConverterException {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {
        Firm pFirm = (Firm) value;
        return pFirm.getName();
    }
}
```

Instead of `@FacesConverter(forClass=Firm.class)`, I also tried `@FacesConverter("firmConverter")`.

I don't get any errors.

How do I get the converter to work so that it displays `Firm#getName()` instead of `Firm#toString()`?

Comment: The `forClass` should work. The name wouldn't work as you used `convert` instead of `converter`. What exactly is `faces-config-general.xml`? Is it referenced as `javax.faces.CONIG_FILES`? Further, are you really using JSP? This is deprecated since JSF2. In future JSF questions, please use `[jsf]` tag instead of `[java-ee]`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for you help et sorry for the tag :/

My converter was good, the problem came from

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{configBean.user.firm}" convert="firmConverter" required="true" label="#{bundle.config_form_add_firm}" > 
<f:selectItems value="#{configBean.firmsLazyList}" />
```

We need to use a List of Firm and not a LazyList.

Hope it could be helpful for someone else.

And thanks for all.